# Ability to access NFC settings on Android Wear programmatically

Tags: java, nfc, wear-os

I have an Android Wear 2.0 watch (Huawei Watch 2) with NFC. Having NFC on in the background, I've found, uses up a lot of battery so I've made an app that lets me easily turn it on before using Android Pay and turn it off after.

One hiccup though: while I can easily directly launch into WiFi settings with

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
```

I can't launch into NFC settings with `Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS` (the settings app opens but crashes) nor into all Connectivity settings with `Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS` (the settings app never opens).

So, how can I programmatically launch directly into the NFC pane of Settings rather than just into the Settings app on my Android Wear 2 watch?

**Edit:** I've tried the standard way of doing it on Android phones, which is to launch either NFC_SETTINGS or WIRELESS_SETTINGS, but both fail, and I'm looking for info on how to get around that on a watch, so my question is definitely not a duplicate.

I'm open to any solution, from an Accessibility service to an intent to a hidden activity I'm not aware of.

Comment: @worker_bee Both very old posts

Comment: I agree regards to that!

Comment: @worker_bee Already tried everything in those answers, don't work on my watch (as described) even if they do work on phones.

Comment: @owlswipe did you look at how PhoneGap implements it behind the scenes. https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/src/android/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/NfcPlugin.java

Comment: @worker_bee There's a lot of stuff going on there. What exactly are they doing?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note, to make sure it works.

AndroidManifest.xml should have permission for NFC settings:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
</config-file>
```

And the usage for creating new Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Still not working. The `startActivity(i)` line crashes my app and triggers the error: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }`. Any other ideas on how to get into the NFC activity of settings directly?